# Are GameObject objects nullable by default?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I noticed that I can type:

```
GameObject myObject = null;
```

Why am I able to do this? I'm new to C# but I believed that to define a nullable varibale I should type a ? after the type. Something like this:

```
GameObject? myObject = null;
```

Why is this not the case?

Comment: `Why am I able to do this?` Because [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) is a **class** in UnityEngine. If you are that new to `c#` maybe a general beginners course would be recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# every variable of a reference type can be assigned null, in contrast to variables of value types which always have a value assigned and can never be null.

That said, there is an optional language feature called [Nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) which is not available in Unity, because Unity has no C#8.0 support.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you initialize variable myObject it may be used when you assign something to it conditionally

```
GameObject myObject = null;
If(some condition) { //Depending on condition instantiate different prefab
    myObject = new GameObject(1);
}
else {
    myObject = new GameObject(2);
}
//Do something with new object
```

Now nullable variables are used with methods/functions where they may not be initialized and you are fine with it. For example you may get a null value from database or api.

Also in first case the type is GameObject and in second the type is nullable which has its own methods

Additionally for value types like integers (unlike reference types like classes) you NEED to use nullable type:

```
int? i = null;
int j = null; //this won't work;
```

As null is not a value but a reference (or more like lack of it)